# Iron Router waitOn not working when setting data on a route in Meteor 1.0.2

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm defining a route that will show an appointment for a patient. I would like the template to show both the patient information and the appointment information.

I have this published:

```
Meteor.publish('userAppointment', function(appointmentId){
  check(appointmentId, String);
  var userId = Appointments.findOne(appointmentId).patientId;
  return [
    Appointments.find({_id: appointmentId}),
    Meteor.users.find({_id: userId}, {fields: {profile: true, emails: true}})
  ];
});
```

Unfortunately Iron Router doesn't seem to be successfully waiting on the data subscription to complete before it tries to set the data context.

Note where I put debugger:

```
Router.route('/admin/appointment/:id', {
  name: 'AppointmentShow',
  waitOn: function(){
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe("userAppointment", this.params.id)
    ]
  },
  data: function(){
    var appointmentId = this.params.id;
    debugger

    var patientId = Appointments.findOne(appointmentId).patientId;

    return {
      appointment: Appointments.findOne(appointmentId),
      patient: Meteor.users.findOne(patientId)
    }
  }
});
```

At the time when debugger stops the code, when I do `Meteor.users.find().fetch()` and `Appointments.find().fetch()` in the console only the currently logged-in user (me) is available and there are no appointments available.

I expect to see two users (me and the patient) and one appointment available because that's the data that should be available after the `waitOn` has finished subscribing.

Am I missing something here?

EDIT----- Still doesn't make sense to me ------

When I change my route to this:

```
Router.route('/admin/appointment/:id', {
  name: 'AppointmentShow',
  waitOn: function(){
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe("userAppointment", this.params.id)
    ]
  },
  data: function(){
    var appointmentId = this.params.id;
    return {
      appointment: Appointments.findOne(appointmentId),
      // patient: Meteor.users.findOne(Appointments.findOne(appointmentId).patientId)
    }
  }
});
```

`Appointments.findOne(appointmentId)` returns an object:

```
{
  _id: "23efref34qr2",
  reason: "coughing",
  patientId: "785g45g4f"
}
```

When my data function only returns

`appointment: Appointments.findOne(appointmentId)`

it works. But if I have it also return

`patient: Meteor.users.findOne(Appointments.findOne(appointmentId).patientId)`

I get an error message (can't read property 'patientId' of undefined.) Huh? It was just defined on the line above!

Comment: Pretty sure that's the expected behaviour - iron-router will render a loading template instead of running your action function, but I don't think it makes any difference to the `data` function, which will run once and then *rerun reactively* when the subscription is ready.

Comment: Ohhh... I see. In my case I should probably just move my data stuff into template helpers and rendered callbacks then, huh? I was hoping to make it available in data so that I could have easier access to the info using `this`.

Comment: Bah, I still don't get it. I've updated the OP.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve, to be honest. There is, as far as i can tell, now way of knowing which subscriptions will be ready before your data route runs - it's asynchronous. You just need to write client code that works when they're not ready and then reactively updates (almost immediately) when they are.

Comment: The thing is that when I return only `Appointments.findOne(appointmentId)`, everything works. If everything is happening async then the `Appointments` collection subscription shouldn't be available at the time the `return` code runs. And yet it is available and `findOne` is able to provide an object to the return statement. But when I try and do the same thing with the `Meteor.users` collection, it no longer works.

Comment: But in your second example you're not starting the debugger! So, unless that's an omission, the subscription is almost certainly ready by the time you query the collection as you haven't stopped JS. I've been thinking about this for a while, and i cannot think of a single scenario in which stopping the data function and querying application state would be useful - just let it run (as many times as necessary when data is receieved) and then if your app state isn't what you think it should be when all the data has been received, *then* start playing around with the data function.

Comment: Debugger or not, when I do `return {
      appointment: Appointments.findOne(appointmentId),
      patient: Meteor.users.findOne(Appointments.findOne(appointmentId).patientId)
    }` I get an error saying that `patientId` is undefined. The error goes away when I only do `return {
      appointment: Appointments.findOne(appointmentId)
}`

Comment: Understood - as a general rule in Meteor, you need to check for the existence of documents before you try to return one of their properties. That way your data function/helper won't throw an error (although it might temporarily return no data) and it will then rerun when data is received. I should probably have mentioned that earlier...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify, I think you should be allowing your data function to run (and rerun when collections are populated), but be careful to make sure your function doesn't throw an error when it runs before data is available. This is a general Meteor pattern.

```
data: function(){ 
  var appointmentId = this.params.id,
        appointment = Appointments.findOne(appointmentId);
     return { appointment: appointment,
    patient: Meteor.users.findOne(appointment ? appointment.patientId : null) } 
  }
```

Sorry about the formatting, I'm doing this from an awful phone...

Comment: I see. That works! I don't see this mentioned ANYWHERE in the Discover Meteor Book, the Meteor Docs (full), or the Iron Router Guide. Where are you supposed to go to read up on these "general Meteor patterns??

Comment: Good question. It's probably worth raising with the various document auths.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that it runs the data function() before running the waitOn, and is therefore timing dependent. I have seen the same problem, and also had to check if the data was actually there.